# Implementing the winding number of a 1D Hamiltonian

Tags: python, eigenvector

The winding number of a 1D Hamiltonian is given by

\begin{equation}
w = \frac{i}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \langle \psi_{k} | \partial_{k} |\psi_{k} \rangle dk
\end{equation}

where $\psi_{k}$ is the eigenvector of the Hamiltonian.

To calculate the above quantity, I have implemented the following script.

```
def winding_number(Nk, mu, delta):
    krange = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, Nk)
    v = np.zeros((len(krange), 2), dtype=complex)
    for i, k in enumerate(krange):
        _, vec = np.linalg.eigh(Hamiltonian(mu, delta, k))
        v[i] =vec[0]

    # Compute the derivative of the eigenvector with respect to momentum
    dvdk = np.gradient(v, krange, axis=0)

    wn=0
    for i, k in enumerate(krange):
        wn += v[i]@dvdk[i]
    wn *= 1j/np.pi
    return wn
```

where the Hamiltonian reads

```
def Hamiltonian(mu, delta, k):
    J = 1 
    hz= J * np.cos(k) + mu/2
    hy= delta * np.sin(k)
    H=np.zeros((2,2), dtype=complex)
    
    sigma_x = np.matrix([[0, 1], [1, 0]])
    sigma_y = np.matrix([[0, -1j], [1j, 0]])
    sigma_z = np.matrix([[1, 0], [0, -1]])

    H= hz*sigma_z +hy*sigma_y
    
    return H
```

For `mu=0.` and`delta=1.`, the code should give `wn=1.0`, e.g., see Eq.(5) in [SciPost Phys. 6, 026 (2019)](https://scipost.org/SciPostPhys.6.2.026/pdf).
I, however, obtain `wn=0` using the above code.

Do you have any suggestions to resolve the issue?

Comment: When you execute the `winding_number` function step by step in a debugger, at which point does it start to do something  different than you expected?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Everything looks fine to me as I tried to implement the first equation[somehow the latex does not work here.]. However, the final sum does not give me what I expect from the literature.

Comment: So you mean all values `v[i]@dvdk[i]` are what you expect them to be and the iteration `for i, k in enumerate(krange):` also does what you expect?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Strangely, Yes! I have checked `v[i]@dvdk[i]` for some test vectors and the results look correct. The loop over `krange` also seems fine.